# Disabling Android Button if Text Fields Empty

Tags: android, layout, button, android-edittext

Can someone tell me how to disable a button in Android unless all three editText fields are filled? I'm not sure where to include a conditional statement here and how to place it in the context of the button listener.

Here's my main activity code.

```
package com.amritayalur.mypowerschool;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MyPowerSchoolActivity extends Activity {
Button buttonSubmit;
TextView textViewTitle;
TextView textViewDesc;
EditText editTextURL, editTextUser, editTextPass;

String url = "";
 String str;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    buttonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
    textViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    textViewDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);

    editTextURL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextURL);
    editTextUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser);
    editTextPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPass);
    //Start TextView
    textViewTitle.setText("MyPowerSchool");


    //button listener
    buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent( MyPowerSchoolActivity.this, creds.class);    
            i.putExtra("pschoolurl", editTextURL.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("pschooluser", editTextUser.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("pschoolpass", editTextPass.getText().toString());
            // get the text here
            final int result = 1;
            startActivityForResult(i, result); 

        };




    });




}       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very Simple, Just update your onClick() method with following code,

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if (  ( !editTextURL.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !editTextUser.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !editTextPass.getText().toString().equals("") ) ) 
        {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent( MyPowerSchoolActivity.this, creds.class);    
            i.putExtra("pschoolurl", editTextURL.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("pschooluser", editTextUser.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("pschoolpass", editTextPass.getText().toString());
           // get the text here
           final int result = 1;
           startActivityForResult(i, result); 
        }
    };
```

The Above if condition will not disable your Button , but it will allow only if your All EditText are not empty.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the TextChangeListener

```
    EditText ed = //your EditText
    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //Check if 's' is empty 

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

How about that:

```
  //button listener
    buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!"".equals(editTextURL.getText().toString())
            && !"".equals(editTextUser.getText().toString())
            && !"".equals(editTextPass.getText().toString())){

              Intent i = new Intent( MyPowerSchoolActivity.this, creds.class);    
              i.putExtra("pschoolurl", editTextURL.getText().toString());
              i.putExtra("pschooluser", editTextUser.getText().toString());
              i.putExtra("pschoolpass", editTextPass.getText().toString());
              // get the text here
             final int result = 1;
             startActivityForResult(i, result); 
        }            
    };




});
```

And if you want to disable button:

```
             buttonSubmit.setEnabled(false); //disable button;
```

Comment: the method equal(String) is undefined for the type String?

Comment: I changed it to equals and the error went away; should it be "equals"?

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake. It's equals